# AVL Tree Insertion changes the root

Tags: c, avl-tree

I have to implement an AVL Tree in C.
I wrote the following insert-Method, but it only keeps changing the root of the tree.

I think it has something to do with how I go through the tree. I know how to do it when only a node is needed for the function, but how do I do it with an entire tree?

```
void AVL_insert(AVLTree* avlt, int value){

    AVLTree *tree = avlt;
    AVLNode *root = avlt->root;

    if(tree->root == NULL){
        AVLNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(AVLNode));
        node->value = value;
        node->height = 0;
        tree->root = node;
        tree->numberOfNodes = avlt->numberOfNodes+1;
        return;
    }
    else if(value < tree->root->value){
        tree->root = root->left;
        AVL_insert_value(tree, value);
    } 
    else if(value > tree->root->value){
        tree->root = root->right;
        AVL_insert_value(tree, value);
    } 
    else return;
    

//..add height, balance tree

}
```

Structs:

```
struct AVLNode{
struct AVLNode* left;       
struct AVLNode* right;  
struct AVLNode* parent;
int value;
int height;
};

struct AVLTree{
struct AVLNode* root;
int numberOfNodes;
};

typedef struct AVLNode AVLNode;
typedef struct AVLTree AVLTree;
```

Comment: Why do your AVL nodes have a parent as well as left/right? Do you need this?

Comment: Yes, I need the parent-node for the balancing.

Comment: It's a bit odd to modify the root *before* recursing with `AVL_insert_value`.
Normally, you add the node as a leaf and re-balance.

Comment: btw.. why you don't update `parent` in `if(value > tree->root->value)` branch?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to delete the first update line. `tree->root->parent = root` returns an invalid write error.

Comment: @Tuorp, nope, you don't need a link to the parent, if you pass up an indicator that the full subtree has grown a level, the reequilibrating can be done in the parent on return from the recursive subroutine.  Other thing is that you for example, implement  an iterator and you don't want to store in it the full chain of nodes to the iterator's pointed to node.

Answer (score 0):

My guess what is wrong.

1. Inserting to an empty node allocates the root, it's left and right children are set to NULL.

```
AVLNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(AVLNode));
```

`calloc()` set the content of the node to zeros.

2. A new value is inserted. As a child is updated *before* recursion, the root is set to its left or right child. Both of them are NULL.

```
tree->root = root->left; // root->left is `NULL`
```

Now, the root is NULL.

3. Adding a next value. The root is NULL. Go to point 1.

As result a new value is alternately added to either empty or 1-element tree.

Possible fix:
Do not update root's children. Just insert a value into the tree as leaf and let re-balancing code optimize tree's depth while returning from recursion.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. In which line do I update the child?